# How to Display the logo in Sign In page using Windows Azure active directory login in Windows Store 8.1 app?

Tags: active-directory, windows-store-apps, azure-connect

am developing a windows store 8.1 app which uses Windows Azure active directory for Single Sign-On.

I have implemented it. I want to add my app logo in the Sign In page,

I Have performed the steps which are explained in the below URL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn532270.aspx

I have added all the necessary logos(with mentioned pixels) but

Still i'm unable to see the logo  in the sign in page.

After 2 to 3 hours of uploading the logos  i have checked the app and still it is not displaying the logo

How to display the logo in the sign in page?

Comment: The page says "User will see a branded sign in page when they visit a service with a tenant-specific URL such as `https://outlook.com/contoso.com`, or `https://mail.contoso.com` (if you’ve created a CNAME)", yet your question doesn't address this at all.

Comment: The pages says "Company branding is a feature that is only available when you enable Azure Active Directory Premium", yet your question doesn't address this at all.

Comment: my windows azure account has Microsoft Azure active directory premium trial